# JSON Data Binding Window Store App Using C#

Tags: c#, json, binding, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to fetch `Items` from a text file, in JSON format (Data.txt):

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Store",
    "Items": [
      {
        "Lev": "1",
        "Brand": "Imported"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now all I want is to show all these `Items` in a separate listview, with 
`Name` used a the Heading on top. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ViewModel create Properties:

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set
    {
        if (_name != value)
        {
            _name = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Name)));
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerable<JsonObject> _items;
public IEnumerable<JsonObject> Items
{
    get { return _items; }
    set
    {
        if (_items != value)
        {
            _items = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Items)));
        }
    }
}
```

and method

```
void ParseJson(string json)
{
    var obj = JsonArray.Parse(json)[0].GetObject();
    Name = obj.GetNamedString("Name");
    Items = obj.GetNamedArray("Items");
}
```

In View create ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Header="{Binding Name}" />
```

Comment: First of all Thank You very much but it seems quiet complicated to me, Can you please prepare easy one? I would be very grateful to you :-)

Comment: @MohammadHani Could you tell me where is Data.txt file located? Is it in LocalData folder?  And what is the structure of Items? Is this simply list of elements with Lev and Brand properties?

Comment: It is located in Assets folder i.e (ms-appx:///Assets/Data.txt/.json), Have you used Split App in visual studio? I want to create a binding example similar to that. :)